# "UnknownError" creating a Booking through the Microsoft Graph Bookings API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I'm trying to use the "Booking Business" endpoint in Microsoft Bookings through the graph API, but the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/bookingbusiness-post-appointments?view=graph-rest-1.0) is not very clear on how to get it working. I am authenticating correctly, and everything appears to work, but I can't seem to actually trigger appointment creation and I can't find any way to get more meaningful feedback on why my requests are failing.

The core request I am sending looks like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/MyCalendar@MyOrg.com/appointments
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "serviceId": "a98309e9-3104-411f-q681-71c7df95a178",
    "duration": "PT30M",
    "start_date_time":
    {
        "dateTime": "2022-12-22T14:30:00+00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "staffMemberIds":
    [
        "e220feb5-5bc-43c6-922z-a2cd5a545ec2"
    ],
    "isLocationOnline": true,
    "filedAttendeeCount": 1,
    "reminders@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingReminder)",
    "reminders":
    [
        {
            "message": "Remember your important appointment today",
            "offset": "PT120M",
            "recipients": "allAttendees"
        }
    ],
    "customers":
    [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingCustomerInformation",
            "name": "Barrington Visitor",
            "emailAddress": "visitor@visitor-organisation.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

This brings a response that looks like this:

```
{
 "error":{
   "code": "UnknownError",
   "message": "",
   "innerError":{
      "date": "2022-11-01T15:27:06",
      "request-id": "72e0b067-6347-4cb9-9257-04db4765908a",
      "client-request-id": "72e0e061-6347-4cb9-9127-0fdb47a590aa"
   }
  }
}
```

I have found two known causes of bugs here - if one doesn't include the `@odata.type` on the `customer` section that will raise an `InvalidModel` error with the message `changes: Cannot create an abstract class.` Apparently [on other endpoints](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer-v4/issues/2043) using a timezone other than UTC causes the same `UnknownError` message to be raised, but I have switched all my timezones to UTC so I'm hoping that specific cause has been avoided. Something is clearly still a problem, though.

When I look at the request-id in the AAD portal it just shows a successful authentication, no mention of errors being raised subsequently.

Obviously that request is far more minimal than the example in the documentation, so I have gradually gone through and added more and more fields from the object, even ones that seem to be completely unnecessary. Even when the request looks like this, I get the same response:

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingAppointment",
    "customerTimeZone": "UTC",
    "serviceId": "a98309e9-3104-411f-q681-71c7df95a178",
    "serviceName": "Appointment Service",
    "serviceNotes": "",
  "smsNotificationsEnabled": false,
    "serviceLocation":
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.location",
        "address": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "displayName": "Online meeting",
        "locationEmailAddress": null,
        "locationType@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.locationType",
        "locationType": null,
        "locationUri": null,
        "uniqueId": null,
        "uniqueIdType@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.locationUniqueIdType",
        "uniqueIdType": null
    },
    "startDateTime":
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2022-12-22T14:30:00+00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "endDateTime":
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.dateTimeTimeZone",
        "dateTime": "2022-12-22T15:00:00+00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
      "duration": "PT30M",
    "postBuffer": "PT5M",
    "preBuffer": "PT1M",
  "price": 0,
  "priceType": "free",
   "priceType@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingPriceType",
    "staffMemberIds":
    [
        "e220feb5-5bc-43c6-922z-a2cd5a545ec2"
    ],
    "isLocationOnline": true,
    "maximumAttendeesCount": 1,
    "filledAttendeesCount": 1,
    "reminders@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingReminder)",
    "reminders":
    [
        {
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.bookingReminder",
            "message": "Remember your important appointment today",
            "offset": "PT120M",
            "recipients@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingReminderRecipients",
            "recipients": "allAttendees"
        }
    ],
    "customers@odata.type": "#Collection(microsoft.graph.bookingCustomerInformation)",
    "customers":
    [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.bookingCustomerInformation",
            "name": "Barrington Visitor",
            "emailAddress": "visitor@visitor-organisation.org",
            "phone": null,
            "notes": null,
            "location": null,
            "timeZone": "UTC",
          "customQuestionAnswers": []
        }
    ]
}
```

This now has all the properties that the documentation example includes, except some of the `address` fields are null and there is no `location` associated with the customer as I'd have to fabricate one. In both cases adding the fields in question does not resolve the issue.

Has anyone found a way to resolve or even usefully troubleshoot this "UnknownError" message? Alternatively, is there something wrong with my requests that I have missed and would avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the solution is, but I finally got an appointment created - the trick was to create an appointment directly through the Microsoft front-end, then go to `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/solutions/bookingBusinesses/MyCalendar@MyOrg.com/appointments` to get a copy of the appointment that created. The JSON object returned was what the service expects so I was able to use that as the basis for successful calls.